# how to use dark theme, translation and searching on docsify.js?

Tags: python, pycharm, github-pages, docsify

source here: https://github.com/VladKochetov007/quick_trade.github.io

docsify: https://docsify.js.org/#/

my tree:

```
project
 └── quick_trade.github.io
      ├── docs
      │    ├── .nojekyll
      │    ├── index.html
      │    └── README.md
      └── README.md
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in index.html:

```html
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/docsify-themeable@0/dist/css/theme-simple-dark.css">
  ...
</head>
```

or other dark theme on https://docsify.js.org/#/themes